# fclose does not close audio file

Tags: c++, windows, file, visual-studio-2019

I have the following C++ code to write shorts to a headerless audio file:

```
vector<short>nShrtDecoded;
nShrtDecoded.resize(iCountDecodedShorts);//-1

//Then I fill the vector of short with some audio. I didn't write that length code here. I think it doesn't matter anyway HOW exactley I fill this vector of shorts

FILE* outfile = fopen("d:\\!wavs\\weg.raw", "wb");
fwrite(&nShrtDecoded[0], sizeof(short), nShrtDecoded.size(), outfile);
fclose(outfile);
```

I run this code in Debug mode, and I have set a breakpoint in the line following the "fclose(outfile)" line.

As soon as this breakpoint is hit, I try to delete this file using the Windows Explorer. This should work as the file has already been closed using "fclose".

When I try to delete the file "d:\!wavs\weg.raw", Windows tells me "File in use: The action could not be completed as the file is in use by a different program":

[image]

As I didn't think that this is true, I fired up LockHunter. LockHunter told me the following:

[image]

Does anybody know what this strange behaviour could be caused by?

Comment: If you try to delete it before the call to `fopen`, does it work?

Comment: Are you sure the debugger you use stops the program after executing the line you have set a breakpoint on? write a `printf` after and make a breakpoint on that instead.

Comment: Are you sure you are actually opening the file? You never check the file pointer

Answer (score 1):

I found the culprit:

I run this in a parallel_for.

That explains everything. :-)